# When do new faction warfare plexes spawn?

Tags: eve-online

With the recent Crucible expansion CCP changed the spawning mechanics of the faction warfare plexes, allowing them to spawn more often. Capturing as many plexes as possible is essential for switching occupancy of a system, so understanding which factors affect plex respawning could help to maximize the number of plexes available.

I've heard conflicting information about whether players inside a captured plex can block the spawning of further plexes.

I'm curious about the following aspects of plex spawning:

- How often do new plexes spawn?
- What factors prevent new plexes from spawning?

Answer (score 2):

According to a source I found new faction warfare plexes spawn every thirty minutes.

Comment: Please share that source

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from dev blogs and experience:

There can only be a certain number of FW 'plexes in a given constellation. This number may or may not be dependant on the statuses of the local solar systems. When there is not enough open 'plexes and there is a check made by the server, a new one has a chance to open for each missing one.

However, I have no idea about how often the "ticks" that checks if enough 'plexes are spawned run.

About factors that prevent a FW 'plex from despawning, from what I understood, once completed they will now despawn no matter if there is still a ship on the grid. (Which prevents an exploit: letting covert ships in there so they stay open and there is less margin for new ones to pop.)

As you can see, quite a difficult problem to solve. But the rule of thumb would be, if you want to open new 'plexes in a constellation, attack the other ones. The more you complete, the more will spawn.